# DTS DB2 Connection Problem

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2000, db2, dts

I want to copy an Oracle Database to a DB2 one using DTS in SQL Server 2000.

When I set up both connections using their respective driver, I can read both databases, and link the copy operations between them.

But when I want to run the DTS package, an error shows up saying "Driver not capable."

Here's the log, thanks in advance.

> Step 'DTSStep_DTSDataPumpTask_1'
>   failed
>
> Step Error Source: Microsoft Data
>   Transformation Services (DTS) Data
>   Pump Step Error Description:The number
>   of failing rows exceeds the maximum
>   specified. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider
>   for ODBC Drivers (80004005): [IBM][CLI
>   Driver] CLI0150E  Driver not capable.
>   SQLSTATE=S1C00) Step Error code:
>   8004206A Step Error Help
>   File:sqldts80.hlp Step Error Help
>   Context ID:0

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to check the driver information and see if you can get a newer version from either Microsoft or IBM. You can also try going through an ODBC connection with a machine DSN. I believe that a lot of people had this problem when upgrading to SP 4 of SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unchecking the "Use Transactions" checkbox on the Advanced tab of the DTS package properties?